# How to activate new adminhtml theme in Magento?

Tags: themes, magento

I developed a new module under Magento, it works well. I designed a new adminhtml theme, however I don't find from where to activate it. I browsed all the backend and found only [design change] which change the store theme..

Is there a way to tell Magento to use my theme?

Comment: Are you the 1st person ever to theme admin? I haven't seen one before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within **config.xml** under **etc** folder of your module, add the following

```
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <design>
                <package>
                    <name>NameSpace</name>
                </package>
                <theme>
                    <default>theme</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
```

Assuming you created your theme under **app/design/adminhtml/NameSpace/theme**